Can not connect to sql server docker image
I used the following command to create the container.

docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e
"MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" -p 1438:1438 -d
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server

Obviously changing the password
Then I open SSMS and in the connection I have server name as

localhost,1438

Authentication is set to

SQL Server Authentication

Login is set to

sa

Password is set to my password
I click connect and get the following error

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
remote host.) (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)
For help, click:
https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10054-database-engine-error

Now I can connect to all sorts of DBs through SSMS without any issue, from azure based ones to local dbs.
Why can I not connect to the docker one? The container is showing as running without error in Docker Desktop.

Does this answer your question? A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Although the linked question is about connecting programmatically, you can also set the said option trustservercertificate in the SSMS connection dialog if you expand the addtional options

The article was not much help as it seems more specific to connection issues from .net apps etc. I have tried setting trustservercertificate but still get the same error.

Is the normal SQL Server port 1433?  That also needs to be the second docker run -p value (the two port numbers don't need to match).

Okay... My own dumb fault.
I did not notice that it kept shutting down. Basically I had not made the sa password strong enough.
Fixed now.
